# How to integrate testers in agile develop environment?

Tags: testing, agile, scrum

We work with Scrum and I think we are on the right way, but one thing bothers me: the testers aren't part of the development cycle yet. Now I am thinking on how to involve the testers in the development team. Now it is seperated and the testers have their 'own' sprint.

Currently we have a C.I. environment. Everytime a developer has finished a user story, he checks in his code and the build server builds the code on every check-in.

What I want is that the testers test the user stories in the same sprint the user story is implemented. But I am struggling on how to set this up.

My main question is: where can the tester test the user story? They can't be testing on the build server because on every check-in it creates a new build and there are a lot of check-ins . So that's not an option. So, should I create a seperate server where the testers can deploy by theirself? Or..

My question is, how have you guys set this up? How have you integrated the testers in the develpment process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a staging server and deploy a build every once in a while. Thats how we do it: CI->Dev->Staging->Live

Edit: I always feel like an asshole posting wikilinks but this article about Multi-Stage CI is good: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-stage_continuous_integration

Comment: Do you have some documentation where this is explained? A link or something?

Comment: Thanks. I never heard of a staging server. I will dive into that :)

Answer (score 2):

In my current project we have 4 small teams and each has 1 Tester assigned. The testers are part of the daily standup, sprint planning meetings etc. The testers also have their own daily standup so they can coordinate etc.

During the Sprint Planning Meeting 2 we create acceptance criteria / examples / test cases (however you want to call it) *together* (testers, developers and PO). The intend is to create a common understanding of the user story, to get the right direction and to split it into smaller pieces of functionality (scenario/test case) e.g. just a specific happy path. Thereby, we are able to deliver smaller working features, which can than be tested by the testers. Meanwhile the next part of the user story can be implemented.
Furthermore, it is decided which stories need an automated acceptance test and  what level (unit, integration, gui test) makes most sense.

As already mentioned by OakNinja :) you will need at least one additional environment for the testers.
In our case those environments are not quality gates, but dev stages. So, whenever a developer finishes some functionality he tells the tester that he can redeploy if he wants to.

If the user story is finished it will be deployed on the staging server, where the acceptance of the user story will be made.

Deployment process:

Dev + Test => Staging (used for acceptances) => Demo (used for demoing user stories each 2nd week) => SIT and End2End Testing Environments (deployed each 2nd week) => Production (deployed roughly all 6 months)

Comment: Thanks. And when do you deploy to the additional environment (staging server)?

Comment: I added it to the answer :) If you have more questions do not hesitate to ask

Comment: Thanks again. This is what have in mind too. Developer mark an item as ready for test, the testers decide when to deploy their staging server and perform their tests. When a test fails, the cycle starts all over again. The only question I have left is, from where do you do a deploy to the life server?

Comment: Well, that depends actually and I do not think that there is THE right answer. In our case its something like that: (dev + test) => staging (used for acceptances) => demo (used for demoing user stories each 2nd week) => SIT and End2End Testing Environments (deployed each 2nd week) => Production; We have a release all 6 months and that are the stages a feature goes through.

Comment: You say dev + test => staging. This differs from what I have in mind. I was thinking about dev => deploy to staging => perform test => test => test OK? -> yes => done -> No => back to dev

Comment: Well ... dev => test environment =>  Test OK? yes = Great; no = fix it. If all Tests of a certain user story are ok than it is deployed on the staging where the PO can verify it.  But is of course possible to do such a process for smaller chunks (scenarios) of a user story and do partial acceptances, which would fit to your description. But actually I think we are talking about the same :)

Comment: But in your case, I suppoes you have a build server where the developers do their check-ins on and I think you have a seperate testserver (not the staging server). So this makes 4 servers, right? Development server (aka the build server), test server, staging server and off course the 'Live' server.

Comment: You can add as many steps/stages as you like, and what works for you. Say you have a test group for alpha and test group for beta releases. Then you'd probably need another server.

Answer (score 2):

We have QA resources involved throughout the sprint: Estimation, Planning, etc.  When the devs first start coding, the QA members of the team start creating the test cases.  As code gets checked in, it gets deployed out to a separate environment on a scheduled basis (or as needed) so that QA can execute their tests during the sprint.  QA is also involved in regression after the stories have been mostly completed.

Our setup uses automated deployments using build configurations in TFS or TeamCity, depending on the project.  Our environments are split like this:

1. **Local development server**.  Developers have own source code, IIS, and databases (if necessary) to isolate them from each other and QA while working.
2. **Build server**. Used for CI, automated deployments.  No websites or DBs here.
3. **Daily Build environment** (a.k.a. 'Dev' or 'Dev Test').  Fully functioning site where QA can review work as it is being done during the sprint and provide feedback.
4. **QA lab** (a.k.a. 'Regression' or 'UAT').  Isolated lab for regression testing, demos, and UAT.

We use build configurations to keep these up to date:

1. CI Build on checkins to handle checkins from local devs.
2. Daily scheduled build and automated deploy to Daily Build environment.  Devs or QA can also trigger this manually, obviously, to make a push when needed.
3. Manual trigger for deploy to QA environment.

Comment: Thank you Jay. This is exactly what I have in my mind. I'm happy with your post. It indicates that I'm on the right track :)

Answer (score 1):

One point is missing from the explanations above, the best way to add your testers into the SCRUM process is by making sure they are part of the scrum team and work together with the rest of the team (devs, PO, etc) in the Sprint.  Most of the time this is not really done, and all you end up having is (in the best case) a Mini-Waterfall process.

Now let me explain.  There is little to add to the extensive hardware and environment explanations above, you can work with staged servers, or even better make it an internal feature to have the scripts in place that will allow testers to create their own environments when they want to (if you are using any CI framework chances are you already have all the parts needed in there).

What is bothering me is that you said that your testers "have their 'own' sprint".

The main problem that I've seen when getting testers involved into the SCRUM process is that they are not really part of the process itself.  Sometimes the feeling is that they are not technical enough to work really close to developers, other times developers simply don't want to be bothered by explaining to testers what they are doing (until they are finished - not done!), other times it is simply a case of management not explaining that this is what is expected from the team.

In a nutshell, each User Story should have a technical owner and a testing owner.  They should work together all the time and testing should start as soon as possible, even as short "informal clean-up tests" in the developers environment.  After all the idea is to cut the Red Tape by eliminating all the unnecessary bureaucracy in the process.

Testers should also explain to developers the kind of testing they should be doing before telling the QA they can have a go on the feature.  Manual testing is as much the responsibility of the developer as it is of the tester.

In short, if you want to have testers as part of your development, even more important than having the right infrastructure in place, you need to have the right mind-set in place, and this means changing the rules of the game and in many cases the way each person in the team sees his task and responsibility.

I wrote a couple of post on the subject in my blog, in case I didn't bother you too much up to now, you may find these interesting.

[Switching to Agile, not as simple as changing your T-Shirt](http://qablog.practitest.com/2011/09/switching-to-agile-testing-not-as-simple-as-changing-your-t-shirt/)

[Agile Thinking instead of Agile Testing](http://qablog.practitest.com/2011/03/agile-thinking-instead-of-agile-testing/)

Comment: Very good answer for a first time post.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to read the article "[5 Tips for Getting Software Testing Done in the Scrum Sprint](http://www.methodsandtools.com/archive/testingscrum.php)" by Clemens Reijnen. He explains how to integrate software testing teams and practices during a Scrum sprint.